Новые тайлы Tilemap не отображаются Unity
У меня такая проблема: Есть скрипт, который прорисовывает дополнительные тайлы, если игрок заходит за пределы уже отрисованных тайлов. У меня изначально есть область уже отрисованная в редакторе, но когда через скрипт функцией SetTile пытаюсь поместить новый тайл, он отображается на сцене, но не отображается в игровом окне, как это иcправть?


 if (!TileM.HasTile(TileM.WorldToCell(Player.transform.position) + (Vector3Int.right)))
 {
     TileBase t = TileM.GetTile(Vector3Int.zero);
     TileM.SetTile(TileM.WorldToCell(Player.transform.position) + (Vector3Int.right), t);
 }




